# Access bean using @AutoWire outside component scan

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Project which is written using Spring and am having trouble with `@Autowire` of a bean. The declaration of the bean

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames" value="classpath:messages"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

The bean is being autowired without issue in my class `BaseController` which falls under the component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.webservice.controller" />
```

I want to `@Autowire` in another class `MessageEnum` which does not fall under the `component-scan`. I have tried to add `autowire="byType"` and `autowire="byName"` to my bean declaration but the autowiring still did not work.

Please find here also my code for the `MessageEnum` class

```
public enum MessageEnum{
    ENUM1("someparam"),
    ENUM2("someparam2");

    @Autorwire
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private String param;

    //Constructors & getParam and setParam methods

    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here for the `messageSource` to be autowired?

EDIT

I tried to create the `MessageEnum` as a bean as advised here. I created the default constructor
        `MessageEnum() {}`

and set the bean in my xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageEnum" class="com.myproj.webservice.util.MessageEnum">
```

but receive the error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageEnum' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.myproj.webservice.util.MessageEnum]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myproj.webservice.util.MessageEnum.<init>()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set new scope for component-scan? I.e. "com.myproj"?

Comment: I have a lot of other classes under that package that don't need to be scanned. My concern is scanning classes uselessy may have an adverse affect on the permformance of the project. If you can do that why don't you just have it scan the entire project right away and avoid ever having these issues?

Comment: Oh god... seriously? Did you even google: "Does component-scan affects performances"?

Comment: Have you tried wiith `@Qualifier("messageSource")` ?

Comment: Component scan affect performance at startup only.

Comment: @BranislavLazic and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314922/does-performance-of-spring-component-scan-depend-on-the-size-of-the-scanned-pack
"... the number of classes matters. You have to scan only packages witch contains annotated classes"

 so found it better to go ahead and ask advice from people more experienced than I am

Comment: why dont you create bean of MessageEnum in your xml, that will solve your problem

Comment: @FranMontero I have tried @Qualifier("messageSource") and it didn't work

Comment: You want to autowire inside enum. I have never came across this type of auto-wiring.

Comment: @Keval I have tried your method, created a default constructor in `MessageEnum` and keep receiving the error message "Could not instantiate bean class ... No default constructor found"