# Spring Data JPA - slow creating beans for repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

**History**

In my project i have around 50 JpaRepositories. Most of them are in the main web app WAR. A few are in 6 external JARs which are compiled into tha main WAR.  My Application Server is Wildfly 8.2.0 Final. I foudn out today in the logs that creating Spring beans from JPA Repositories takes on my machine **20 seconds**. I have an not so old i5 and an SSD. I have Spring 4.2 and Spring Data JPA 1.9.4.

**Question**

This is way too long. **Anyone knows how to speed up bean creation for Spring Data JPA Repositories or at what mistakes to look for?**

**Additional Info**

I configured the Spring Data JPA as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"pl.company"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEmf")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"pl.company"})
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {
```

Here are the logs from Wildfly 8.2.0:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/540c79a4e8456a28aa52a2ea640553b0

The repeating fragment which takes so long:

```
14:30:13,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
14:30:13,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
14:30:13,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
14:30:13,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver] (MSC service thread 1-3) Resolved classpath location [pl/company/] to resources [URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/classes/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/energetyka-coretypes-1.1.2-umarsz.jar/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/energetyka-wicket-components-1.0.4-umarsz-SNAPSHOT.jar/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/licensing-1.0.8.jar/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/reports-1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/system-parameters-1.2.1.jar/pl/company/], URL [vfs:/C:/Java/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/BDOS.war/WEB-INF/lib/wicketWebComponents-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/pl/company/]]
14:30:14,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver] (MSC service thread 1-3) Resolved location pattern [classpath*:pl/company/**/*GokCommunity2016Table4RepositoryImpl.class] to resources []
14:30:14,296 DEBUG [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (MSC service thread 1-3) Spring Data JPA - Registering repository: gokCommunity2016Table4Repository - Interface: pl.company.zaprogs.web.statements.repository.gok2016.communityStatement.GokCommunity2016Table4Repository - Factory: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean
```

Comment: The component scan can take some time to discover and initialize the beans. Whether you can speed up the initialization process depends on what percentage of your total Java classes are Spring-managed beans. If the majority of them are managed through Spring, you should not expect to get too much improvement through any possible technique. Otherwise, you can get rid of component scan and instantiate your beans manually. Linking you to another post which discusses both techniques.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring startup performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947713/spring-startup-performance-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading Spring Data JPA from 1.9.4 to 1.11.10. This particular part executes now in 3 instead of 52 seconds.